# Unity platform arm rotation with weapon offset

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, trigonometry

Hello I'm having trouble with calculating the rotation of my characters arm to account for the guns offset from the shoulder pivot to aim the muzzle of the gun at the mouse. But when it rotates the arms it also has to update the new weapon offsets causing the guns rotation to jitter if the mouse position + weapon offset is closer then the muzzle of the gun.

```
public void rotateArm(){
    Vector3 centerPosition = armPivotPos.position;
    Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)+updatedWeaponOffset();
    mousePosition.z = armPivotPos.position.z;
    Vector3 dir = centerPosition - mousePosition;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * -Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    Quaternion temp = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, -Vector3.forward);
    armPivotPos.eulerAngles = new Vector3(temp.eulerAngles.x, temp.eulerAngles.y, temp.eulerAngles.z);  
}
public vector3 updatedWeaponOffset(){
    Vector3 weaponOffset = armPivotPos.position - muzzlePos.position;   
    return weaponOffset;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is using Inverse Kinematics with the arm not an option? You'd only need to calculate the movement of the gun, constraining the arc and distance.

Comment: Thank you Happy Apple! I've got a simplistic IK solver going and it seems like it will work very well in this situation. But if anyone is able to point me to the correct equation for my original question that would awesome. Cause I've ran into this problem on other things that IK is not an option.

Comment: I've tried implementing Ik for this but I still run into an issue with the offset of the gun. By what I understand(Not much) is I need something closer to Forward Kinematics. I think I have found a post that explains how to do what I need. Here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58692/how-do-i-target-a-tank-turret-with-an-offset-barrel?newreg=ea94618c571742fe815ae409b02f91ad . But for the life of me I can't wrap my head around the math.